# Crope image in multiimager library

Tags: android

Client  has given me  a requirement  that he  can  click  3 images  using  camera . I have  used  this  library  https://github.com/vansikrishna/Multimager for  image  but  it  gives  me  list  of  images  in  onactivity  result  . I have  to  crop  the  image  after  each  click. I want  that  If  I click  first  image  crop action  perform  then  second  again  crop image  like  that

Comment: Please edit your question. Provide more details and frame the question as if you are trying talking to a two-year-old. For example, what do you mean by click 3 images using a camera?

Comment: Hi  Kamarudeen,  if you visit  the  link  which  I have  given then you  will  understand  that what  it  means  click  3 images, I am  taking  about  clicking  three  images  from  camera  one  after  another. Android  does not  provide  such a  functionality so  we  use  surface  view  and  other  things  and  called  camera  from  hardware